# at commands to send image/ audio clip though sms

Tags: sms, at-command

i have used AT commands previously to send a simple text message from PC to mobile via gsm modem. this is the [link](http://www.developershome.com/sms/) i referred to.  However, I was wondering if is it possible to send images or short audio clips using AT commands. I have searched a lot but couldn't find any source. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible for a GSM modem. You may need a GPRS modem instead. But I wonder if there's a standard for sending MMS, although it's clear that some manufacturers have their own AT commands set. On my putal modem the commands are `AT^UPLOADFILE`, `AT^MMSSEND` and `AT+EMMSEXE`. You could refer to your own modem's dev manual.

Comment: if i use my phone(samsung galaxy-y) as a modem, will it support this? also, i want to send an ems message, not an mms message